# NSTableView Header Style

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

When an NSTableView has the style NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular, the group rows have a very nice background and design overall. 
I'd like a NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList Table view, but with the same header style.

Has anyone an idea how to do this, without having to subclass it?

Comment: Are you using a 10.7 view-based NSTableView or a regular cell-based one? With the view-based, NSTableRowView is responsible for drawing the selection highlight.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a 10.7 view based table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no other way then subclassing it, but it's pretty easy:
Just make a subclass of NSTableRowView, override the DrawRect method.
Check the property self.isGroupRowStyle. If it is, then write the code to draw it.
Else just call [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

In the TableView Delegate, return an instance in the 
tableView:rowViewForRow: Method.

thanks anyway